# How to access data on a selected row of struts jquery grid plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jqgrid, struts2, grid

Here's a brief code of the Grid:

```
 <s:url id="remoteurl" action="jsontable"/>
<sjg:grid
    id="gridtable"
    caption="Items Result"
    formIds="gridSearchForm" 
    reloadTopics="reloadItemsGrid"
    dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    pager="true"
    gridModel="gridModel"
    rowList="10,15,20"
    rowNum="15"
    rownumbers="true"
    navigator="true"
    navigatorSearch="true"
    navigatorRefresh="true"
    viewrecords="true"
    width="600"
    pagerInput="false"
    pagerPosition="center"
    recordpos="right"
    direction="rtl"
    onSelectRowTopics="rowselect">

    <sjg:gridColumn name="title" index="title" title="title" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="price" index="price" title="price" formatter="integer"/>
```

and the subscribe function:

```
$.subscribe('rowselect', function(event, data) {
alert('Selected Row : ' + event.originalEvent.id);
});
```

The id accessed is the event.originalEvent.id id of the row from the database of the item.

How do I access the price and title parameters of the selected row? Can someone give an example for the syntax to be used? is it through data or event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
$.subscribe('rowselect', function(event, data) {
var grid = event.originalEvent.grid; 
var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'); 
var price = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'price'); 
alert(price); });
```

This solves the problem :)